# Resnet50 achieves lower top1 accuracy than Mobilenet on imagenet

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Keras documentation states that **resnet50** has 0.75 top1 accuracy, while **mobilenet** has only 0.7, which makes sense since mobilenet is lighter.

However, testing these two models on an **imagenet** validation dataset(2012) yields 0.695 accuracy for mobilenet and 0.68 for resnet50. How can resnet be less accurate than mobilenet upon this dataset?

*Below is the code for testing resnet50.*

**Preprocessing:**

```
def prepare_image_resnet50(file):
    img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array_expanded_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

    return keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(img_array_expanded_dims)
```

**Inference:**

```
predictions = []
for i in range(10000):
    j = i + 1
    num = fill_zeros(str(j))
    img_name = fixed + num + '.JPEG'

    image_t = prepare_image_resnet50('H:/Datasets/imagenet/2012/'+img_name)
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_t, dtype=tf.float32)
    prediction = model.predict(image_t)
    predictions.append(prediction[0])
```

**Measuring accuracy** (with one-hot encoded labels):

```
def top1_accuracy(predictions, labels):
    acc_sum = 0
    num_of_samples = len(predictions)

    for i in range(num_of_samples):
        true_class_index = np.argmax(labels[i])
        pred_class_index = np.argmax(predictions[i])

        if true_class_index == pred_class_index:
            acc_sum += 1

    return acc_sum/num_of_samples
```

Please let me know if the resulted accuracy values make sense or if there's some error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

A better option should be classic resize and center crop:

```
img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(256, 256))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = tf.image.central_crop(image, 0.875) # 224/256
img = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

return keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(img)
```

Tipically preprocessing for ImageNet include a resize to a image_resolution + 32 and then cropping the center part of the image.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).